# Remove first n elements by group from table

Tags: group-by, kdb

Say I have the following table:

```
t:([]date:25#(.z.d+ til 5); travel:(5#`car),(5#`plane),(5#`bus),(5#`cycle),(5#`scooter); val:25?100)

date       travel  val
----------------------
2019.12.06 car     75 
2019.12.07 car     47 
2019.12.08 car     70 
2019.12.09 car     32 
2019.12.10 car     86 
2019.12.06 plane   29 
2019.12.07 plane   96
```

How do I remove the first `n` observations (assuming they do not start all on 2019.12.06) by `travel` column?

For instance, in that particular example, if `n=1`, I would only get entries where date>2019.12.06.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use following code snippet:

```
n: 3;
select from t where i>({last[y]^y@x-1}[n];i) fby travel
```

In above statement all row numbers are grouped by travel and first `n` of them are removed. `{last[y]^y@x-1}[n]` returns `n`th rownum value or last rownum, if `n` is larger than number of rows in group.

Answer (score 3):

Below would work (courtesy of `iasc`) in cases where the data is not necessarily *sorted* by date:

```
q)select from t where 0<(iasc;date) fby travel
date       travel  val
----------------------
2019.12.07 car     30 
2019.12.08 car     75 
2019.12.09 car     61 
2019.12.10 car     56 
2019.12.07 plane   46
...
```

Wrapping in a function as you describe:

```
q){[tbl;skipNum]select from tbl where (skipNum-1)<(iasc;date) fby travel}[t;1]
date       travel  val
----------------------
2019.12.07 car     30 
2019.12.08 car     75 
2019.12.09 car     61 
2019.12.10 car     56 
2019.12.07 plane   46
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take advantage of the use of a simple `by` clause. We can get the indices of rows by travel easily enough

```
q)exec i by travel from t
bus    | 10 11 12 13 14
car    | 0  1  2  3  4
cycle  | 15 16 17 18 19
plane  | 5  6  7  8  9
scooter| 20 21 22 23 24
```

From this we can drop `n` results, raze the indices and index back in

```
q)n:1
q)t asc raze value exec _\:[n;]i by travel from t
date       travel  val
----------------------
2019.12.07 car     10
2019.12.08 car     1
2019.12.09 car     90
2019.12.10 car     73
2019.12.07 plane   43
2019.12.08 plane   90
2019.12.09 plane   84
2019.12.10 plane   63
2019.12.07 bus     54
2019.12.08 bus     38
2019.12.09 bus     97
2019.12.10 bus     88
2019.12.07 cycle   68
2019.12.08 cycle   45
2019.12.09 cycle   2
2019.12.10 cycle   39
2019.12.07 scooter 49
2019.12.08 scooter 82
2019.12.09 scooter 40
2019.12.10 scooter 88
```