# How can I drop the first 252 rows by sym?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with sym-date indexing.

I'm trying to get the same table back, but skipping the first 252 rows for each symbol.

I expected it would be:

```
ungroup 252_select by sym from t
```

but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove first n elements by group from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209872/remove-first-n-elements-by-group-from-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for something like this

```
select from t where 252<=(rank;i) fby sym
```

where `rank` returns the position in the sorted list and `fby` is used to apply this function to each subset of `i` when split on sym

Reasons why your attempt wasn't working

- `select by sym from t` returns only the last row for each sym
- therefore when you drop rows using `252_` you are dropping 252 last rows
- `ungroup` is then likely failing because you have a two or more columns with different length vector elements

If you wanted to do this via `ungroup` you could do the following using `xgroup` as to keep all the rows in the grouping

```
ungroup 252_/:/:`sym xgroup t
```

Comment: This is the kind of conciseness kdb is about! However I think `iasc` would get the same result as `rank` in this case as your i column will be sorted anyway within each sym?

Comment: Good point! It does improve the slightly improve the performance

Answer (score 1):

`select from t where 1=({x>252};i) fby sym`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an admittedly more convoluted solution:

```
t:([] date:.z.D+til 1008;sym:(504#`A),(504#`B);px:1008?1.0); / test table
s:252; / # of elements to skip
ungroup (key tt)!{flip (x)_flip y}/: [s;tt[key tt:?[t;();((,)`sym)!(,)`sym;`date`px!`date`px]]]
```

The logic involves:

- grouping by `sym`
- assigning the result on the fly to table `tt`
- processing the grouped dictionary one by one
- reconstructing the table

Now, I initially tried to benchmark vs the `fby` solution proposed above testing against a very small table, and the solution using `fby` is 50% faster:

```
t:([] date:.z.D+til 10;sym:(5#`A),(5#`B);px:10?1.0);
s:2;
\t:100000 ungroup (key tt)!{flip (x)_flip y}/: [s;tt[key tt:?[t;();((,)`sym)!(,)`sym;`sym`px!`sym`px]]]
796
\t:100000 select from t where s<=(rank;i) fby sym
396
```

However, when the larger table proposed at the beginning (1008 rows in total, first 252 skipped per ticker) is used, the performance ranking changes:

```
\t:100000 select from t where s<=(rank;i) fby sym
2384
\t:100000 ungroup (key tt)!{flip (x)_flip y}/: [s;tt[key tt:?[t;();((,)`sym)!(,)`sym;`sym`px!`sym`px]]]
1679
```

Comment: It's interesting to see a performance comparison between these. Adding a grouped attribute on the sym column seems to reduce this gap somewhat. I would be inclined to use xgroup instead of a grouped function select for readability